# How to access <asp:placeholder> in other tags

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web

I have a navigation bar on my page.

```html
<ul>
  <li><asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></li>
  <li>Register</li>
  <li>Login</li>
</ul>
```

Now have another `Placeholder` which I am accessing in my **webpage.cs** file like this

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal{Text = li.ToString()};
```

`li` here is a `StringBuilder` I declared earlier.
This `PlaceHolder1` is outside the navbar in the `body` and I can access it But how can I access the one in the navbar, the `PlaceHolder2`.

Comment: How about `PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(new Literal{Text = "Another link"};`

Comment: No for this one When I type PlaceHolder2 which its ID 
the visual studio says that Placeholder2 does not exists in the current context

Comment: Maybe `PlaceHolder2` is in the `MasterPage` file but not in the page itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(PlaceHolder1.FindControl("PlaceHolder2") as PlaceHolder)
```

Comment: I don't get it can you explain more?